# Registration wizard with MvvmCross (on iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I need to implement a registration wizard on iOS with three different views. I'm using MvvmCross and I'm confused how to deal with the RegistrationViewModel.

My idea: I have one RegistrationViewModel and three different ViewControllers / Views. Each view will add some data to the VM. After the third step I send all the data to the server.

How to achieve this goal? Is it possible to use only one ViewModel or do I need three different VMs (each per view) and a cache instance which stores the registration data until third step is complete?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make RegistrationViewModel have three view models of its own, something like step1vm, step2vm, step3vm?

This is something I do for example with tabs in a page, main vm and a vm for each tab inside the main vm.

Comment: I tried this. But you can not reuse the RegistrationViewModel (needs to be singleton) on all three views. ShowViewModel<Step1VM> gives my a new instance of Step1VM, but its not associated to the RegistrationViewModel.Or do you have a singleton RegistrationViewModel and on ShowViewModel<Step2VM> you do something like mySingletomRegistrationVM.Step1ViewModel = this